# JavaFX Textfield to MySQL INSERT: SQL Syntax Error

Tags: java, mysql, sql, javafx

I have a MySQL Table which looks like this:

[image: MYSQL Table]

I made some Textfields in my form and saved the input as Strings:

```
    String name = shopname.getText();
    String address = streetaddress.getText();
    String city = cityname.getText();
    String state = statename.getText();
    String country = countryname.getText();
    String zip = zipcode.getText();
    String phonept1 = phonecountryid.getText();
    String phonept2 = phoneareaid.getText();
    String phonept3 = phoneothernumber.getText();
    String phonefull = phonept2 + " " + "(" + phonept1 + ")" + " " + phonept3;
```

Then I just made an INSERT method which worked well with the old SQLite Database:

```
            conn = DBConnect.Connector();
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO shopList (name,address,city,state,country,zipcode,phonefull) VALUES(" +name+ "," + address + "," + city + "," + state + "," + country + "," + zip + "," + phonefull + ")");
            conn.close();
```

But now it says:

SEVERE: null
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(22) 222222)' at line 1

Anyone see the syntax error?

ps. (22) 222222 is the tested phonefull input.

Comment: The values inside the `VALUES ( ... )` are unquoted. This cannot possibly work. And you should use prepared statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
conn = DBConnect.Connector();
stmt = conn.createStatement();
stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO shopList (name,address,city,state,country,zipcode,phonefull) VALUES('" +name+ "','" + address + "','" + city + "','" + state + "','" + country + "','" + zip + "','" + phonefull + "')");
conn.close();
```

Try this (I have wrapped your string VALUES in single quotes)

**edit:**

You are leaving yourself vulnerable to **SQL injections** by passing string values directly. When possible you want to use the `PreparedStatement` object and `setString` method.